# How can I automatically verify that all web.config transforms have the same elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm working on an ASP.NET project that has several web.config transformations that are generated at build time (all at once, using MsBuild); one .config file for each deployment environment.

EX:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <TransformXml 
           Source="Web.Base.config"    
           Transform="Web.DevServer1.config"
           Destination="ConfigBuild\Web.DevServer1.config" />
      <TransformXml 
           Source="Web.Base.config"    
           Transform="Web.QAServer1.config"
           Destination="ConfigBuild\Web.QAServer1.config" />
      <!-- ... -->
      <!-- ... -->
  </Target>
```

Each transformation has several elements whose values are substituted into the base web.config file. Management and I are concerned that a necessary element could potentially be overlooked by mistake in one of the transformation files.

Is there a way to automatically verify that none of our transformation files are missing any elements, using either MsBuild or some other VisualStudio tool?

Preferably, this check would be carried out at build time.

Comment: Off topic, but the problem of WCT is that something that should essentially be known and static ahead of time (like config per environment) is not fully defined until you build your system.   If you want to make a change you technically must rebuild.  This makes it difficult to separate the two which should certainly be the case.

Comment: Do you resolve the issue, if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes this answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is there a way to automatically verify that none of our transformation files are missing any elements, using either MsBuild or some other VisualStudio tool?

You can create a custom task, which compare the config file by using XmlDocument class, if they are different, use Log.LogMessage to output the node message. Like this:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using System.Xml;

namespace Common
{
    public class SimpleTask3 : Task
    {
        private string myProperty;

        // The [Required] attribute indicates a required property.
        // If a project file invokes this task without passing a value
        // to this property, the build will fail immediately.
        [Required]
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                myProperty = value;
            }
        }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            // Log a high-importance comment
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "The task was passed \"" + myProperty + "\"");
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(myProperty + "/web.base.config");

            XmlDocument sDoc = new XmlDocument();
            sDoc.Load(myProperty + "/ConfigBuild/Web.DevServer1.config");

            //compare with them and check the different.

            //if different

            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "different message");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!--<Message Text="BuildDependsOn: $(BuildDependsOn)" />-->
    <Message Text="Inside of BeforeBuild, time: $([System.DateTime]::Now)" />
    <TransformXml Source="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\Web.Base.config" Transform="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\Web.DevServer1.config" Destination="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\ConfigBuild\Web.DevServer1.config" />
    <TransformXml Source="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\Web.Base.config" Transform="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\Web.QAServer1.config" Destination="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2\ConfigBuild\Web.QAServer1.config" />
  </Target>

  <UsingTask TaskName="Common.SimpleTask3"
        AssemblyFile="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\Common\bin\Debug\Common.dll"/>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <SimpleTask3 MyProperty="D:\Project\Msbuild\App1\App2"/>
  </Target>
```